# How can i send an Confirmation email when Registered email id Was changed by customer?

Tags: magento-1.9, email, ce-1.9.0.1

In My account after login, the customer can change the registered email id.I want to send a confirmation mail to the customer whenever the email id is changed. Please let me know how I can achieve it. I am using Magento 1.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

For check email id has changed you have to create observer and check two events namely **customer_save_before** and **customer_save_after** and get email in both the observer if found change you can send email.

#### create a module for example Smashing_Meta

create Smashing_Meta.xml and put it on **app/etc/modules**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Smashing_Meta>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Smashing_Meta>
    </modules>
</config>
```

create config.xml inside **app\code\community\Smashing\Meta\etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Smashing_Meta>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Smashing_Meta>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <smashing_meta>
            <class>Smashing_Meta_Model</class>
        </smashing_meta>
    </models>
</global>
<global>
    <events>
        <customer_save_after><!-- observe the event -->
            <observers>
                <smashing_meta>
                    <class>smashing_meta/observer</class>
                    <method>autoMailAfter</method>
                </smashing_meta>
            </observers>
        </customer_save_after>
    </events>
    <events>
        <customer_save_before>
            <observers>
                <smashing_meta>
                    <class>smashing_meta/observer</class>
                    <method>autoMailBefore</method>
                </smashing_meta>
            </observers>
        </customer_save_before>
    </events>
</global>
```

create Observer.php inside **app\code\community\Smashing\Meta\Model**

```
<?php 

class Smashing_Meta_Model_Observer {   


public function autoMailAfter($observer) {
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
    $emailnew = $customer->getEmail();

    if(!$emailold==$emailnew){
    $this->writeMsg($email1);

}

} 
public function autoMailBefore($observer) {
    if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){            
        $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
        $emailold = $customer->getEmail();
    }

} 

public function writeMsg($emailold) {

    //put code for send mail

}

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your code. I have a still a problem. In my account when i add a invalid email id, then also it is saving the id. If the invalid email id is added we cannot send an email confirmation mail. Please help me on how i can solve this.........

Comment: Hi Pavan, Can i get any solution.when i add a invalid email id, then also it is saving the id. If the invalid email id is added we cannot send an email confirmation mail. Please help me on how i can solve this

Comment: Yes i checked but magento defaults check for email validation .when i enter  invalid email it gives me error.

Comment: Hi Pawan, My problem is not related to email validation. Suppose if my email id is "madhan@gmail.com". If i have added a email id as "mahan@gmail.com"(spelling change) then in this case the submitted email id will be saved but an confirmation email wont be sent to the email id. I hope you understood my problem...

Comment: i got your point but you should send email to email that is used to registered first time.second thing i dont know how to validate this thing. because how you know that email exist or not .or you can enable Require Emails Confirmation first time a user registered.  thanks

Comment: @madhan, Have you got your working solution ?